# Applying an image texture in shader patch in Spark AR

Tags: augmented-reality, spark-ar-studio

In my Spark AR project, I have a material that is set to a `Shader Asset` patch.

In the main patch I send a texture which I have loaded as an asset, and then inside the shader patch I try to use `Vertex Attribute : Texture Coordinates` in conjunction with the `Texture Sampler` and pipe this directly to the shader patch's color output ... but it isn't working ... Any idea why ?

[image: main patch sending in the texture]

[image: shader patch]

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you haven't connected your patchAsset to the material.

In your main patch editor, you need to have the 'patchAsset' output connected to the input of a material. To create a yellow 'input' patch, click the arrow under the Parameters section in the inspector panel. The patches inside the 'patchAsset' look fine.

The project window should look something like this.

[image]